# Zoom hangs ArcGIS API for JavaScript application?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, cartography, zoom

I'm using ESRI arcgis 3.13

I have map with minZoom set to 3.

When user tries to zoom in to level 19, the program just hangs and after a while, comes back with a generic browser error not from the application that says "more memory is needed" etc. So the application is killed during zoom. Shown here:

[image: Error from browser after application hangs]

I tried to debug this, and pinpointed to this line, this is the line where the program would stop and hang, and it is calling an ESRI map method:

```
_map.centerAndZoom([-79, 43], 19);
```

I have this for my map intialization:

```
_map = new Map("myMap", {
    center: [-100, 48],
    zoom: 3,
    basemap: "streets",
    minZoom: 3,
    logo: false
});
```

However, this was all working before, and just stopped work this week.

Also, if I set initial map zoom to be 7, the app hanging problem goes away. So I am thinking if it because the zoom is changing too much. But like I said, the program was working before even with that much of zoom, and it worked before even from zoom level 1 to zoom level 19.

Any ideas how to fix this? Or where to look for potential problems?

Comment: Hi Howe, can you create an example (using a site like jsfiddle or jsbin) to show us the problem happening?

Comment: It could be helpful so see the output in your browser console (press f12 on most modern browsers) - if there is anything there? arcgis api commonly outputs quite useful dojo errors there, which could help with debugging

Comment: This issue has also been brought up (and currently unanswered) on the ESRI forums.  The user who posted the issue there also provided a fiddle.

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/167149

https://jsfiddle.net/dgarcrom/1dbvjqyx/

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround, not a fix, but the issue is a bug introduced by Chrome 46.

I traced the issue down to the dojo module that ESRI uses to handle the map zoom animation, dojo/_base/fx, contained in the ESRI init.js file.

By updating the config to effectively skip the animation, the issue does not occur.

Include the following code in your page initialization:

```
esri.config.defaults.map.zoomDuration = 0; 
esri.config.defaults.map.zoomRate = 0;
```

See the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1dbvjqyx/16/

Comment: Thanks for the answer Totty.  Is the dojoConfig = {async: true}; necessary?  Is it used for esri loading, and so the rest of the application do not get blocked? 

Also, I found that when these zoomDuration/zoomRate is set, the zoom out button is grayed out, and does not come back, even though the button works, see this new problem here:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169032/gis-esri-arcgis-zoom-out-grayed-out